# Grouping by hours without adding non-existing hours in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I wanted to group my df, datetime indexed, into hours. The source data interval is 5 minute, but only from 6am to 6pm, no data for night-hours.

My code is like this:

```
hourly= df.resample('60T').sum().sort_index().dropna(how='any')
```

But, the result produces extra night-time hours to make each day become complete 24 hours. It gives night-time hours zero values. I don't want it. I only need hours that respect the source data.

Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `groupby` with a calculated series, in this case flooring at 1-hourly intervals:

```
# example dataframe
dates = ['2018-01-01 15:01:00', '2018-01-01 15:23:15', '2018-01-01 16:30:05']
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.to_datetime(L), 'values': [1, 2, 3]})

res = df.groupby(df['date'].dt.floor('60min'))['values'].sum()

print(res)

date
2018-01-01 15:00:00    3
2018-01-01 16:00:00    3
Name: values, dtype: int64
```